# Is there a way to skip all errors in GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

To be clear, I would like to skip every forbidden parameter combination.

My GridSearchCV parameters right now is

```
"preprocessor__cat__encoder": [OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'), LabelEncoder(), OrdinalEncoder()],
'classifier':  [
    KNeighborsClassifier(), 
    LogisticRegression(solver="liblinear",random_state=42), 
    SVC(probability=True, random_state=42), 
    DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42), 
    RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42),
    GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=42),
    ],
'classifier__n_neighbors':  [i for i in range (10, 200, 10)],
'classifier__penalty': ['none', 'l2'],
'classifier__C': [10**-2, 10**-1, 10**0, 10**1, 10**2],
'classifier__class_weight':  [None, {0:1,1:5}, {0:1,1:10}, {0:1,1:25}], 
'classifier__max_depth': [5,10,25,None],
'classifier__min_samples_split': [2,5,10],
'classifier__n_estimators':  [10, 50, 100, 250],
```

and I cannot split them into different arrays because I also have preprocessing steps

Clearly, this will throw an error and force stop the entire fitting process.

Is there a way to skip the forbidden parameter combinations (NOT warnings)?

Here's what I've done :

error_score = np.nan

```
gs = GridSearchCV(clf, params, cv=3,  scoring='roc_auc', error_score = np.nan)
```

ConvergenceWarning and FitFailedWarning

```
from sklearn.utils._testing import ignore_warnings 
from sklearn.exceptions import FitFailedWarning, ConvergenceWarning 
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV 

with ignore_warnings(category=[ConvergenceWarning, FitFailedWarning]): 

    gs.fit(x_train, y_train)
```